# Making an inequality true

Tags: logic, inequality, arithmetic

> $n > 10$ implies $n + 3 \leq  \Box\times n$
>
> Possible answers:
>
> - $1$
> - $2$
> - $3$
> - $4$

I answered "$2$" and got it wrong. *Why?*  When $n=2$, $(11) + 3 \le 2(11)$.

> $n > 1$ implies $n + 3 \leq \Box\times n$
>
> Possible answers:
>
> - $1$
> - $2$
> - $3$
> - $4$

I answered "$4$" and got it right.

*Why did I get the 2nd problem right, and the 1st wrong?*

Comment: Your answer is not wrong, it's incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first guess what that this was a question of the sort where you need to select every correct option, but if that were the case, then you would not have gotten the 2nd question correct. So I assume it is a mistake on the part of whoever is grading.

The statement
$$n>10\implies n+3\leq \Box\times n$$
is true for all values of $\Box$ that are greater than or equal to $\frac{14}{11}$. Out of the provided options, this means that the correct ones are $\Box=2$, $\Box=3$, and $\Box=4$.

The statement
$$n>1\implies n+3\leq \Box\times n$$
is true for all values of $\Box$ that are greater than or equal to $\frac{5}{2}$. Out of the provided options, this means that the correct ones are $\Box=3$ and $\Box=4$.

Comment: Thank you.  I think you're right - about selecting all the correct options.  I'm just plugging in numbers for the blank "variable" and testing the equations with each constant scalar $n$.  Why would $3$ be a correct value for the blank in the 2nd question?  If $n = (1.1)$, $4.1$ is not $\le$ 3.3.  Also, how did you solve to find the minimum value of the blank space?